# Adding second DC to Cassandra cluster and balancing data

Tags: cassandra, replication, cluster-computing

I have a cluster across two zones in AWS and This is functional and have not issues with it.

It is the Second DC that seems to have issues as it comes up but does not own any data or have any replicated to it. This cluster will be used for reporting and no client doing inserts will run against it.

The following is the schema_keyspaces config:

====

keyspace_name | durable_writes | strategy_class                                       | strategy_options

app           | True           | org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy | {"1":"3"}

====

Cassandra Version 1.2.14

initial_token:

num_tokens: 256

Datacenter: 1

==============

Status=Up/Down

|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving

--  Address       Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack

UN  10.1.1.22   122.7 MB   256     37.5%             12ae63ef-3757-4b42-872e-bdd26d0dea50  1

UN  10.1.1.23   133.07 MB  256     37.7%             05771659-b117-4c7a-9a71-c5fd0dc976c1  1

UN  10.1.1.20   131.4 MB   256     40.3%             5310a111-0954-4d2b-aeff-eb2d3150faff  1

UN  10.1.1.21   129.81 MB  256     36.7%             3e94252d-19cd-4334-918e-f4df980a452a  1

UN  10.1.2.20   110.57 MB  256     33.8%             9bf87f06-0617-4ace-abf8-fa418c05a0eb  2

UN  10.1.2.21   132.05 MB  256     37.4%             6b89460e-74f3-4b96-8363-d3fe5c413f48  2

UN  10.1.2.22   125.58 MB  256     38.4%             ae11a4f2-9956-4b26-8e3d-16425c76f916  2

UN  10.1.2.23   124.12 MB  256     38.1%             53c93e96-c490-4d98-bb89-cbdc71e0346d  2

Datacenter: 2

==============

Status=Up/Down

|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving

--  Address       Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack

UN  10.2.2.22  187.4 KB   256     0.0%              95caff71-4dca-4e57-97e3-5985e79cd746  2

UN  10.2.2.23  187.33 KB  256     0.0%              91b44d9e-5aab-44b2-8135-670addc2a339  2

UN  10.2.2.20  187.33 KB  256     0.0%              0e5bd1d1-69f8-4851-bfad-e1068835ddd8  2

UN  10.2.2.21  137.93 KB  256     0.0%              29e6aa79-1145-4308-8248-44280ff9f4ad  2

UN  10.2.2.27  163.65 KB  256     0.0%              f471466b-4f6c-4450-8b7e-1225056265f2  2

UN  10.2.2.24  138.03 KB  256     0.0%              07ba8dd1-9bc3-4d51-a903-2853ed09e008  2

UN  10.2.2.25  187.79 KB  256     0.0%              7fa542c5-f85c-4a4a-b641-d7a310710701  2

As you can see it the second DC does not seem to receive data but I can query the keyspace that is on the first cluster from the second cluster.
Why is the data not replicating.

Note the config at the top of this post was used to add nodes to the first cluster and these join the cluster and data balances across without really doing anything else.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have defined datacenter 1 to get 3 replicas, but nothing is defined for datacenter 2

```
NetworkTopologyStrategy | {"1":"3"}
```

You'll need similar to:

```
NetworkTopologyStrategy | {"1":"3", "2":"3"}
```

Comment: Thanks MShuler, I have now done this but data is still not balancing across, are there any other commands that need to be run?

Comment: So now you have defined "the data should be replicated in this manner" and new inserts should be going to the proper locations, but existing data will need to be checked that it exists in all its proper locations.  That sounds like a job for 'repair'  :)

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit of fiddling about I eventually used the following:

ALTER KEYSPACE myapp WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 1 : 3, 2 : 3 } AND durable_writes = 'true';

Then using cluster SSH I connected to all 16 cassandra nodes and did a repair on the keyspace.
This forced out the merkel tree check and balancing of data.

So happy days.